# Adobe Create SDK Image Editor crashes when loading supplies

Tags: android, adobecreativesdk, creative-cloud

I have Adobe Creative SDK Image Editor integrated into my App. Everything works fine, as far as editing is concerned, but when I try to load new supplies (Stickers, Effects, Frames, etc...) that are provided for free by Adobe, a SignUp/SignIn dialog opens up and the App crashes when either of the buttons is pressed. From the crash dump, below, it is evident that the crash happens in the Adobe logic, but maybe I don't have something configured properly. Has anyone had experience with this?

```
133654---------- beginning of crash
133683:09-09 11:22:44.339  4495  4495 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
133754-09-09 11:22:44.339  4495  4495 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.floomit.floomit, PID: 4495
133843-09-09 11:22:44.339  4495  4495 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
134088-09-09 11:22:44.339  4495  4495 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1690)
134191-09-09 11:22:44.339  4495  4495 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
134294-09-09 11:22:44.339  4495  4495 E AndroidRuntime:     at com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.internal.account.IAidlAdobeBillingContentService$Stub$Proxy.login(IAidlAdobeBillingContentService.java:278)
134484-09-09 11:22:44.339  4495  4495 E AndroidRuntime:     at com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.internal.account.AdobeBillingContentManager.login(AdobeBillingContentManager.java:314)
134653-09-09 11:22:44.339  4495  4495 E AndroidRuntime:     at com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.internal.account.BillingContentFactory.requestLogin(BillingContentFactory.java:486)
134819-09-09 11:22:44.339  4495  4495 E AndroidRuntime:     at com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.AdobeImageBillingService.requestLogin(AdobeImageBillingService.java:95)
134973-09-09 11:22:44.339  4495  4495 E AndroidRuntime:     at com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.dialogs.LoginDialogFragment.onClick(LoginDialogFragment.java:281)
135121-09-09 11:22:44.339  4495  4495 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
135221-09-09 11:22:44.339  4495  4495 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
135326-09-09 11:22:44.339  4495  4495 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
135431-09-09 11:22:44.339  4495  4495 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
135536-09-09 11:22:44.339  4495  4495 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
135629-09-09 11:22:44.339  4495  4495 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
135740-09-09 11:22:44.339  4495  4495 E AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
135840-09-09 11:22:44.339  4495  4495 E AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
135973-09-09 11:22:44.339  4495  4495 E AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
136087-09-09 11:22:44.341  4949 31347 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.floomit.floomit/com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.AdobeImageEditorActivity
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following in the manifest

```
<provider
     android:name=“com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.internal.cds.CdsProvider”
        android:authorities=“${applicationId}.CdsProvider”
        android:exported=“false”
        tools:replace=“android:authorities” />
```

Comment: CreativeSDK explicitly mentions removing this provider from the manifest. https://creativesdk.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/211241666-Android-migration-guide-from-0-9-7-to-0-9-1062